# POST request using sockets not working in python

Tags: python

I have the following python code:

```
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
client.connect(("example.com", 443))
client.send(b'POST /api HTTPS/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nAuthoriation: aa\r\nContent-Length: 22\r\n\r\n')
client.send(b'{"jsonPostData": "aaa"}')
response = client.recv(4096)
response = repr(response)
```

But it returns a 400 bad request error with no content, I tried same headers and json with requests and aiohttp and in both it works, any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Usually, using https://pypi.org/project/requests/ is much easier. Did you choose to use `socket` on purpose? If not: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp

Comment: I use it on purpose since it's faster or multiple requests

Comment: do you use connection pools / sessions with aiohttp/requests?

Comment: Why do you say it's faster for multiple requests? Are you trying to make requests to a very distant server? Like requesting a US server from Asia? If so I have some experience using requests in that context. As mentioned pools and sessions are very helpful. There are a few other tips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never write your own http-client, if you're not an expert on TCP, TLS, HTTP(S) and API-design, it would not robust nor convenient.

As for your code snippet - you could not use plain sockets for secure connections, you must use secure sockets.

```py
import socket
import ssl

def request(sock):
    sock.sendall(
        b'POST /post HTTP/1.1\r\n'
        b'host: postman-echo.com\r\n'
        b'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:83.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/83.0\r\n'
        # b'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n'  # do you really want to handle it?
        b'accept: application/json\r\n'
        b'connection: keep-alive\r\n'
        b'content-type: application/json\r\n'
        b'content-length: 14\r\n'
        b'\r\n'
        b'{"qwe": "rty"}'
    )
    return sock.recv(4096)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    tls = True  # toggle 
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        if not tls:
            sock.connect(("postman-echo.com", 80))
            response = request(sock)
        else:
            with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname="postman-echo.com") as ssock:
                ssock.connect(("postman-echo.com", 443))
                response = request(ssock)
    print(response)
```

From response

```
"json": {"qwe":"rty"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I still get the same Bad request response.

Comment: The code from the answer works as is? If you change nothing.

Comment: Yep my fault, chaged the post body  in a wrong way

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to connect to an SSL port using a non SSL connection.

Try using the requests library. Try connecting to port 80.

Comment: It switches to HTTPS automatically, I will edit the comment but that is not a problem.

Comment: what switches to HTTPS **automatically**? the `socket` module is very low-level, there's nothing automatic there

Comment: The webserver redirect me to https